# Constructing smoothing splines with cross-validation

Tags: cross-validation, smoothing, splines

Can someone provide me with a book or online reference on how to construct smoothing splines with cross-validation? I have a programming and undergraduate level mathematics background.  I would also appreciate an overview of whether this is smoothing technique is a good one for smoothing data and whether there are any disadvantages of which a non-statistician needs to be aware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Nonparametric Regression and Spline Smoothing*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824793374) by Eubank is a good book.  You probably want to start with Chapters 2 and 5 which cover goodness of fit and the theory and construction of smoothing splines.  I've heard good things about [*Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584884746), which might be better if you're looking for examples in R.  For a quick introduction, a google search turns up a course on [Nonparametric function estimation](http://www.stat.osu.edu/~yklee/763/note.html) where you can peruse the slides and see examples in R.

The general problem with splines is overfitting your data, but this is where cross validation comes in.

Comment: Good references, but I don't understand your last comment about a parametric distribution. Splines are usually used for modelling the conditional mean of Y|X and are not directly to do with the distribution of either Y or X. I know you can fit spline-based density estimates, but I doubt that is what Henry was asking about.

Comment: Yes, the latter, but due to meandering and unrelated thoughts, not meant for "publication".  I was thinking about density estimation because of some other question and, in light of this question, was working through explaining spline methods to *myself*.  Strangely, I remember thinking what I typed was cogent -- because of what was in my *head*.  Ridiculous.  :-/  Thanks for the catch; impressed that it occurred to you, though I shouldn't be based on your quality answers.